# Trying to unwind two or more arrays in OrientDB

Tags: orientdb

I'm using OrientDB's UI/Query tool to analyze some graph data, and I've spent a couple of days unsuccessfully trying to unwind two arrays.

The **unwind** clause works just fine for one array but I can't seem to get the output I'm looking for when trying to unwind two arrays.

Here's a simplified example of my data:

```
@class       |  amt  | storeID  | customerID  
transaction     $4        1         1
transaction     $2        1         1
transaction     $6        1         4
transaction     $3        1         4
transaction     $2        2         1
transaction     $7        2         1
transaction     $8        2         2
transaction     $3        2         2
transaction     $4        2         3
transaction     $9        2         3
transaction     $10       3         4
transaction     $3        3         4
transaction     $4        3         5
transaction     $10       3         5
```

Each customer is a document with the following information:

```
@class   | customerID | State 
customer     1             NY  
customer     2             NJ  
customer     3             PA
customer     4             NY  
customer     5             NY
```

Each store is a document with the following information:

```
@class   | storeID | State |   Zip 
store         1         NY     1 
store         2         NJ     3    
store         3         NY     2
```

Assuming I did not have storeID (nor wanted to create it), I want to recover a flattened table with the following distinct values: name of the store, city, account numbers, and the sum of spent.

The query would hopefully generate something like the table below (for a given depth value).

```
State | Zip | customerID
 NY      1       4      
 NY      1       5      
 NY      2       1      
 NY      2       4      
 NJ      3       1      
 NJ      3       2      
 NJ      3       3
```

I've tried various expand/flatten/unwind operations but I can't seem to get my query to work.

Here's the query I have that recovers the State and Zip as two arrays and flattens the customerID:

```
SELECT  out().State as State, 
        out().Zip as Zip, 
        customerID 
    FROM ( SELECT EXPAND(IN()) 
            FROM (TRAVERSE * FROM 
                ( SELECT FROM transaction) 
        ) 
    ) ;
```

Which yields,

```
State            |   Zip     | customerID 
[NY, NY, NJ, NJ]   [1,1,2,2]       1   
[NY, NY, NJ, NJ]   [1,1,2,2]       1   
[NY, NY, PA, PA]   [1,1,3,3]       4
[NY, NY, PA, PA]   [1,1,3,3]       4
...                   ....      ....
```

Which is not what I'm looking for. Can someone provide a little help on how I can flatten/unwind these two arrays all together?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not understanding your use case: you use functions like `in()` or `out()` but I don't see a graph type use (vertices and edges). It seams to me that you are using like a document DB.  It would be great if you could share a small export of your db so I can test it.  Thx

Comment: @IvanMainetti transaction is the edge between a customer node and a store node. Is that more clear?

Comment: Hi Francisco, your graph should have a structure similar like this `CUSTOMER` --- `TRANSACTION` --> `STATE` right ? `amt` is the edge property that specifies the value of the transaction ?

Comment: Hi Francisco, about the query you're looking for, which are the corresponding fields that you want to retrieve ? Something like . `name of the store ---> storeID, city ---> field ? (probably Store.State ?) from which table ?, account numbers ---> field ?, sum of spent ---> sum for each store or for each customer ?`

Comment: @LucaS Yes, that's exactly right. I want to retrieve just State, Zip, and CustomerID (I can get to spent) , but what I really want to do is unwind the State and Zip, but I can't figure out how to do that without having CustomerID become an array...I can get State and Zip, but then CustomerID becomes an array or I can get CustomerID and then State and Zip become arrays. Not sure how to get both to be unwound/flattened.

Comment: Hi Francisco, a result like this: 

`-----+----+----------`
`State|Zip |customerID`
`-----+----+----------`
`NY   |1   |1`
`NY   |1   |1`
`NY   |1   |4`
`NY   |1   |4`

Comment: Hi Francisco, I added the answer with two examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your case with this structure (based on your example):

[image]

I used this queries to retrieve State, Zip and customerID (not as array):

1. **Query 1**:

   ```
   SELECT State, Zip, in('transaction').customerID AS customerID FROM Store 
   ORDER BY Zip UNWIND customerID

   ----+------+-----+----+----------
   #   |@CLASS|State|Zip |customerID
   ----+------+-----+----+----------
   0   |null  |NY   |1   |1
   1   |null  |NY   |1   |1
   2   |null  |NY   |1   |4
   3   |null  |NY   |1   |4
   4   |null  |NY   |2   |4
   5   |null  |NY   |2   |4
   6   |null  |NY   |2   |5
   7   |null  |NY   |2   |5
   8   |null  |NJ   |3   |1
   9   |null  |NJ   |3   |1
   10  |null  |NJ   |3   |2
   11  |null  |NJ   |3   |2
   12  |null  |NJ   |3   |3
   13  |null  |NJ   |3   |3
   ----+------+-----+----+----------
   ```
2. **Query 2**:

   ```
   SELECT inV('transaction').State AS State, inV('transaction').Zip AS Zip, 
   outV('transaction').customerID AS customerID FROM transaction ORDER BY Zip

   ----+------+-----+----+----------
   #   |@CLASS|State|Zip |customerID
   ----+------+-----+----+----------
   0   |null  |NY   |1   |1
   1   |null  |NY   |1   |1
   2   |null  |NY   |1   |4
   3   |null  |NY   |1   |4
   4   |null  |NY   |2   |4
   5   |null  |NY   |2   |4
   6   |null  |NY   |2   |5
   7   |null  |NY   |2   |5
   8   |null  |NJ   |3   |1
   9   |null  |NJ   |3   |1
   10  |null  |NJ   |3   |2
   11  |null  |NJ   |3   |2
   12  |null  |NJ   |3   |3
   13  |null  |NJ   |3   |3
   ----+------+-----+----+----------
   ```

**EDITED**

In the following example, with the query you'll be able to retrieve the average and the total spent for every `storeID` (based on each `customerID`):

```
SELECT customerID, storeID, avg(amt) AS averagePerStore, sum(amt) AS totalPerStore
FROM transaction GROUP BY customerID,storeID ORDER BY customerID

----+------+----------+-------+---------------+-------------
#   |@CLASS|customerID|storeID|averagePerStore|totalPerStore
----+------+----------+-------+---------------+-------------
0   |null  |1         |1      |3.0            |6.0
1   |null  |1         |2      |4.5            |9.0
2   |null  |2         |2      |5.5            |11.0
3   |null  |3         |2      |6.5            |13.0
4   |null  |4         |1      |4.5            |9.0
5   |null  |4         |3      |6.5            |13.0
6   |null  |5         |3      |7.0            |14.0
----+------+----------+-------+---------------+-------------
```

[image]

Hope it helps

Comment: you are a hero!! Thank you!!

Comment: Hi Francisco, thank you. Is the answer correct ? Do the queries work correctly ?

Comment: This is perfect! Exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: as a followup, if I wanted to traverse this for a greater depth than zero (because I this query only returns adjacent nodes) would I be able to use inV() and outV()? I'm testing this now and have not been successful. I want to be able to return unwound/flattened data while also extracting a deeper customer base (i.e., with a depth of 1 or 2). This is why I was using a traverse query in the case before...can I make one of the two work?

Comment: Hi Francisco, you could use this query to try the `TRAVERSE` and `MAXDEPTH`: E.g. Retrieve all the `customerID`s connected to the `storeID` = 2 ---> `SELECT customerID AS customerIDs FROM (TRAVERSE in('transaction') FROM (SELECT FROM store WHERE storeID = 2) MAXDEPTH 2) WHERE @class <> 'Store'` ----> `customerIDs = 1, 2, 3`

Comment: BTW, I think that in your case this is not necessary because the relationships in the dataset are `CUSTOMER --- TRANSACTION --> STATE` with depth of 1 and `transaction` is an edge, so you could retrieve the results by using only `out()/in()` or `outV()/inV()` functions. You can also use the `TRAVERSE` operator, but this would be more useful, for example, to traverse a hierarchical structure with more depth levels. Hope it helps.

Comment: The query you provided works, but it doesn't provide the data in the unwound format that we spoke over before. Ultimately, I wanted to be able to calculate aggregation operations on the flattened version. Is there a way to modify the query to do that? Or is this not possible for depth > 1? Thanks again for being so helpful!

Comment: Hi, do you have an example of aggregation which could be used in your case ?

Comment: Yeah, for example, summing the total spent (amt) or counting the total distinct customers (or if I had income for each customer) calculating the average income of shoppers for each store (for a given depth level). Does that make sense? Thanks again.

Comment: Hi Francisco, I'm adding an useful example of aggregation/grouping functions (`avg()`,`sum()`,`GROUP BY`) which can be used in your case. Firstly, to avoid problems with sums and averages, I advise you to change the type of your `amt` property to `DOUBLE` and remove the `'$'` character (this will facilitate the calculations)

Comment: About the `depth`, I think that, in this case, it doesn't make sense because you have a simple relationship `CUSTOMER --- TRANSACTION --> STATE` with `depth = 0` or `1` and you can implement different and more direct queries based on a simple `SELECT`. Hope to have been helpful.